# CR4.PCE for rdpmc is cleared

Tags: performance, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, intel

I try to enable bit 8 (PCE bit) of CR4 on my intel i7-4770K in order to use rdpmc.
then I wrote this module :

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

void printcr4(void)
{
    unsigned long long cr4;
    asm volatile(
        "xor %%rax,%%rax\n\t"
        "mov %%cr4,%%rax\n\t":"=a"(cr4));
    printk("CR4 : %llx\n",cr4);
}
void CR4_enablePMC(void)
{
    asm volatile(
        "mov %cr4,%rax\n\t"
        "or $(1<<8),%rax\n\t"
        "mov %rax,%cr4\n\t"
    );
}
int init_module(void)
{
   printcr4();
   CR4_enablePMC();
   printcr4();
   return 0;
}
void cleanup_module(void)
{
   printcr4();
}
```

I load the module with `insmod`.

The first call of `printcr4` (in `init_module` and before enabling PCE with `CR4_enablePMC`) print me `CR4 : 1406e0` so the bit 8 is 0.

The second call of `printcr4` (in `init_module` and after enabling PCE with `CR4_enablePMC`) print me `CR4 : 1407e0` so the bit 8 is 1.

Then I removed my module with `rmmod` and the last all of `printcr4` (in `cleanup_module`) print me `CR4 : 1406e0`.
So the bit 8 is again 0 but I expected it to be 1 because I don't do anathing between the second and the last call of `printcr4`.
So I guess something else cleared this bit but I don't know what it is.

I tried to execute my module with on_each_cpu function but I have the same results.
I also try to run it in a minimal environment with one process(bash) and one core enabled (I do that via grub) but same result.

Do you know how can I set this PCE bit for a long time?

If it can help, I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

EDIT (the code with smp) :

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

void printcr4(void)
{
    unsigned long cr4=0;
    /* OLD CODE
     asm volatile(
        "push %%rax\n\t"
        "xor %%rax,%%rax\n\t"
        "mov %%cr4,%%rax\n\t":"=a"(cr4));
    asm volatile(
        "pop %rax\n\t");*/
    /* NEW */
    asm volatile(
    "mov %%cr4,%0\n\t":"=r"(cr4));
    printk("Proc: %d, CR4 : %llx\n",smp_processor_id(), cr4);
}
void CR4_enablePMC(void)
{
    asm volatile(
        "push %rax\n\t"
        "mov %cr4,%rax\n\t"
        "or $(1<<8),%rax\n\t"
        "mov %rax,%cr4\n\t"
        "pop %rax\n\t"
    );
}
void init_module_smp(void *param)
{
    printcr4();
    CR4_enablePMC();
    printcr4();

}
void cleanup_module_smp(void *param)
{
    printcr4();
}
int init_module(void)
{
    printk("\nInit module\n");
    on_each_cpu(init_module_smp, NULL, 1);
    return 0;
}
void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk("\nCleanup module\n");
    on_each_cpu(cleanup_module_smp, NULL, 1);
}
```

then I run insmod then rmmod and I get (dmesg) :

```
[ 3438.920809] 
               Init module
[ 3438.920813] Proc: 5, CR4 : 1406e0
[ 3438.920814] Proc: 2, CR4 : 1406e0
[ 3438.920815] Proc: 6, CR4 : 1406e0
[ 3438.920815] Proc: 2, CR4 : 1407e0
[ 3438.920817] Proc: 6, CR4 : 1407e0
[ 3438.920818] Proc: 7, CR4 : 1406e0
[ 3438.920818] Proc: 3, CR4 : 1406e0
[ 3438.920819] Proc: 7, CR4 : 1407e0
[ 3438.920820] Proc: 3, CR4 : 1407e0
[ 3438.920824] Proc: 5, CR4 : 1407e0
[ 3438.920826] Proc: 0, CR4 : 1406f0
[ 3438.920827] Proc: 4, CR4 : 1406e0
[ 3438.920829] Proc: 4, CR4 : 1407e0
[ 3438.920830] Proc: 0, CR4 : 1407f0
[ 3438.920832] Proc: 1, CR4 : 1406e0
[ 3438.920833] Proc: 1, CR4 : 1407e0
[ 3442.120602] 
               Cleanup module 
[ 3442.120610] Proc: 0, CR4 : 1406f0
[ 3442.120624] Proc: 7, CR4 : 1406e0
[ 3442.120625] Proc: 3, CR4 : 1406e0
[ 3442.120626] Proc: 1, CR4 : 1406e0
[ 3442.120627] Proc: 2, CR4 : 1406e0
[ 3442.120628] Proc: 5, CR4 : 1406e0
[ 3442.120629] Proc: 6, CR4 : 1406e0
[ 3442.120643] Proc: 4, CR4 : 1406e0
```

Comment: Can you show us the version of your code that uses `on_each_cpu`

Comment: And your `printcr4` might be more useful if it prints the processor number. Something like `printk("Proc: %d, CR4 : %llx\n",smp_processor_id(), cr4);` . As well at a minimum you should consider at a minimum adding `"rax"` to the clobber list in `CR4_enablePMC` since you destroy _RAX_ .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my message in order to include what you want. I used the stack(push/pop) instead of clobber list

Comment: I am suspicious of your printcr4 routine.  You `mov %%cr4,%%rax`, but then you `pop %rax`.  What will be in the c variable cr4 after this pop?  How about replacing all that asm with just `asm("mov %%cr4,%0" : "=r" (cr4));`?  If you feel strongly about explicitly using rax and that it must be zeroed before use (can't think why, but if you do), how about `asm("mov %%cr4,%0" : "=a" (cr4):"0"(0));`?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd : Why not set _C_ variable `cr4` to zero with `unsigned long long cr4 = 0;` and use `+` instead of `=` on the constraint.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Not sure how that's better, but ok.  The real question is why do either?  It's not like the `mov cr4, rax` might not be able to overwrite all the bits if rax doesn't get zeroed first.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd It's not better from code generation standpoint (same code generated), just one less constraint and probably easier for naive software developers to understand. But yes, the actual code is nonsensical as it is.

Comment: Your logging would be much easier to read if there was one line per init, and it had both the before/after values.  So instead of `printcr4`, define `unsigned long getcr4() { unsigned long cr4; asm volatile("mov %%cr4, %0" : "=r"(cr4)); return cr4; }`.  Since this is kernel code (where x32 isn't a possible compile target), I just used `unsigned long` as a type that will be the size of a register in either `-m32` or `-m64`.  Your asm has bugs and wasted instructions, like David and Michael pointed out.

Comment: Linux might use perf counters internally.  Assuming your buggy code happened to work like you expected, it looks believable that Linux is clearing that bit in cr4 before your module unloads.

Comment: Ok my code is note clean and there is probably wasted instructions. @David Wohlferd I used `pop %rax` because I used `push %rax` before in order to save rax. (Actually I don't think saving rax is useful because I thought that it is the register for return value of a function and so there is no reason rax contains the same value than it contains at the beginning of the function. But I am probably wrong). "What will be in the c variable cr4 after this pop?" cr4 will contains the value of cr4 register. I don't see the reason of why it could have any other value.

Comment: Also I don't understand why it is necessary to set the C variable to 0 but I tried and it doesn't change anything. I also change other things in the code as you suggest me but the result is the same. So I don't really understand why you think my code contains bugs. It is certainly not well coded but it work like I expected. You are probably right of course but can you elaborate?

Comment: @PeterCordes . I think, as you said, that Linux is clearing that bit in cr4 before your module unloads but it is annoying because I can't use `rdpmc` in user space.

Comment: *cr4 will contains the value of cr4 register. I don't see the reason of why it could have any other value.* You tell gcc to put the value of the c variable cr4 in rax (`=a`). On the next line you change the value of rax (via pop). Unless you are doing an unoptimized build, there's a good chance gcc is still using rax for the c cr4 variable, so the pop will change the value of the c variable. Also 'saving rax' is not useful. Just remove the push/pop/xor. rax will be assigned to c cr4 for the duration of this asm instruction (all of 1 statement), then gcc is free to do what it thinks is best.

Comment: `"What will be in the c variable cr4 after this pop?"`: If the compiler thinks it has the `cr4` variable in rax, and then you modify rax without telling the compiler, your code doesn't do what you want.  This happens because you pop rax in a separate asm statement from the one that pushed it, so the compiler can make code that depends on the value before the pop.

Comment: Also note that the function can be inlined, so rax isn't just the probably-unused return value of the function: It could be in use for anything.  See also the [inline assembly tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info).  But the takeaway here is: never modify a register without telling the compiler.  And whenever possible, just use constraints to describe the asm, and let the compiler take care of any and all saving/restoring.

Comment: RE: perf counters from user space: `perf` already lets you use perf counters from user space.  [Agner Fog also has a kernel module + library for making more direct use of perf counters](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#testp).  I haven't looked into the details, and normally just isolate a code fragment into a standalone program and use `perf stat`.

Comment: *never modify a register without telling the compiler. And whenever possible, just use constraints to describe the asm, and let the compiler take care of any and all saving/restoring.* <- Exactly right. I'd just add that whenever possible, also let the compiler pick which *register* to use. Combine all this together and you get the 1 line asm I proposed above: `asm("mov %%cr4,%0" : "=r" (cr4));`. No extra push/pop, no unnecessary zeroing of register, and allows the compiler (which knows exactly how the registers are being used) to pick a safe/cheap register.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some reading and `diff` between kernel versions it appears that the following function in the kernel file arch/x86/include/asm/mmu_context.h is responsible of disabling CR4.PCE :

```
static inline void load_mm_cr4(struct mm_struct *mm)
{
    if (static_key_false(&rdpmc_always_available) ||
        atomic_read(&mm->context.perf_rdpmc_allowed))
            cr4_set_bits(X86_CR4_PCE);
    else
            cr4_clear_bits(X86_CR4_PCE);
}
```

After kernel 4.1.5 (including it) the `static_key_false` was replace by `static_key_true`.

I don't know exactly what is `rdpmc_always_available` but the name is quite understandable.

Instead of modifying the code, we can just do `echo 2 > /sys/devices/cpu/rdpmc` as root user.

Then we can configure PMC as we want (and carefully because there is maybe other processes which use it...).

@PeterCordes @DavidWohlferd @Michael Petch : thank you very much for you help.

Comment: For what it's worth, this [change](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/linux.kernel/j7RSwV-0qKY/SNhNNKWCdgQJ) was some type of hardening to make `rdpmc` unavailable to most user processes to protect against various timing and other side-channel attacks in seccomp sanboxes. If you open any pmu event using `perf_events` you should again also get access to `rdpmc` (that's the `perf_rdpmc_allowed` thing), which is also the recommended way (on Linux) to self-monitor a process (see the `cap_user_rdpmc` section in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html).

Answer (score 0):

This CR4 register is per-cpu.   So if you do everything in one function it is UNLIKELY (but still possible due to interrupts) that your process context can be switched away from the current CPU, and when switching back to continue execution again, it is running on ANOTHER cpu.

Every CPU's CR4 is totally independent of another CPU's CR4.   (Or any registers in fact).

But if there is any global memory like /sys/xxxx or sysctl command, then these values are either stored into global memory, or it is updated into ALL the CPU at the same time.

Comment: I agree and this is why I used on_each_cpu(). This doesn't solve anything because the problem is not due to that.